# button whith an irregular shape

Tags: shapes, css, button

I'm trying to mare a button whith an irregular shape similar to this using only CSS
Somebody have any clue?

[image]

Comment: You could embed an SVG into the CSS.

Comment: Link embedding inside SVG; image map; SVG with pseudo-element; just live with a little live clickable area outside the button image.

Comment: You could get something close in just CSS using `border-radius`, but given your lack of effort into a good question that's as much as I will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with the `border-radius` property to get some odd shapes...

[image]

```
button {
    background: #a00;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #a33;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #aaa;

    /* where the magic happens */
    border-radius: 40% 60% 30% 50%;

}
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/f85ah38g/)

If you need *that* specific shape, you'll have to work out the percentage of radius for each corner to get close.

Comment: That's awesome! exactly what I need! thanks guys!